# Specify a list of arguments in the pylintrc file for "unused-argument"

Tags: python, pylint

Can I specify a list of arguments in the pylintrc file instead of disabling unused-argument altogether?

I need it to avoid messages like this:

W0613: Unused argument 'evt' (unused-argument)

Comment: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#ignored-argument-names? Or just use the conventional `_`, which is covered by the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`--ignored-argument-names` option](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v3.0.3/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#ignored-argument-names) should do what you want.